# "'Sys' is undefined" error running ASP.NET MVC application in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC in my web application. It uses AJAX (MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, jquery-1.3.1.min.js) to make the call from the view to the Delete action with this code:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete the record?", HttpMethod = "Delete", UpdateTargetId = "divAttributeList" }) %>
```

In the controller I uses this code to process the view request:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _service.DeleteAttribute(id);

        return PartialView("List", _service.ListAttributes());
    }
```

It works great when I run it on the ASP.NET Development Server but when I try to run the application on a IIS7 (Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008) I get the error

[image]

If i press Continue, the browser show me the next message

**The resource cannot be found.**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look at the paths for the javascript includes to make sure that they are correct for the path used in IIS7.  I've taken to using Url.Content() to make sure that my paths are defined correctly with respect to the root path of the application.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'
         src='<%= Url.Content( "~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" ) %>'>
 </script>
```

Comment: Right. In particular, "Sys" comes from MicrosoftAjax